# can I do the following with php curl

Tags: php, curl

what I'm trying to figure out if php's curl function is eligible to get in a password protected page, of course with given credentials, and curl a specified page?

Comment: thanks!can you drop me a link with an example beacuse my google shows me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, see this sample code :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'login' => 'foobar',
    'passwd' => 'xxxxxxxxx'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

(From http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/)

The fields names should be edited to suit your needs, see the output of

```
mech-dump --forms http://YOUR_domain.tld
```

(install `mech-dump` if needed)

Comment: POST edited, more specific, and I talk about `mech-dump` application for your toolbox =)